# mirror modifier and then Rotate symmetrically

Tags: mirror

I want to Rotate symmetrically after add mirror modifier
But I can not rotate symmetrically.
How should I do ?[image]

---

I want to copy like this
rotate and copy
[image]

Comment: In Edit mode selecting and rotating your Vertices should produce the result you are looking for. If not please post more details.

Comment: Also, can you explain what happens when you try to rotate, and maybe provide a screenshot of your results?

Comment: I attached the details.please check it